I was deported from Germany. My boyfriend live in Italy he's coming to do marriage, with the marriage certificate will italy give visa?
I was deported from Germany,my boyfriend live in Italy he's coming to Nigeria for our marriage,can I apply for Italy visa with the marriage certificate?

Is your boyfriend a citizen of an EU or EEA country or of Switzerland?

And if he isn’t, what is his status in Italy (visa, resident permit, etc.)?

is your intent to move to Italy after your marriage to live with your fiance, or to go there for short trips while continuing to live in Nigeria?

Why were you deported? How long has the relationship existed and on what basis (eg internet, or long distance between Germany/Italy with periodic face-to-face reciprocal visits)?

I think the Italian (indeed all EU) authorities will be extremely skeptical about the validity of your marriage. Nigeria is one country where a lot of scams originate after all, including marriage scams intended to get people easy EU residence permits.
